# Magento 2.3.5: Move breadcrumbs into the header

Tags: magento2, php, header, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to move the breadcrumbs into the header, right now it displays outside of it.

What I mean is as follows:

[image]

the above shows the breadcrumbs being outside of the header, I want it to be a part of the header.

The location of the breadcrumbs file is as follows.

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

The breadcrumbs display only on the catalog and product pages and I want it to stay that way.

How can I get the breadcrumbs to be included/nested in the header?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to move the breadcrumbs block in XML.
So in the app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="your destination" before="xxx"/>
```

Comment: When I do that the breadcrumb disappears all together <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="header" before="main.content"/> currently it displays only on the category and product pages and I want it to stay that way.

Comment: <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="header" before="minicart"/>
You have to add it like this.
"main.content" isn't the header element.

Comment: That didn't work either, I'm not sure it this is something to do with the theme.